# Testing autocompletion in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse Plug-in which provides property auto-completions with a `ICompletionProposalComputer` contributed via the `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal`.

I'd like to create automated tests for the functionality but have no idea where to start. How can I write automated tests for my proposal computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple [SWTBot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot) test. Once I have the editor open, it's pretty simple to get a list of autocompletions:

```
bot.editorByTitle("index.html").toTextEditor();
editor.insertText("<html>\n<div  ></div>\n</html>");
editor.navigateTo(1, 5);
editor.getAutoCompleteProposals("")
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago a colleague and I had a similar problem while implementing a `IContentAssistProcessor` for a `SourceViewer` [based editor in a console view](http://rherrmann.github.io/gonsole/).

We started with an integration test that simulated a <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> key stroke within the console editor and expected a shell with a table that holds the proposal(s) to show up.

Here is such a test case: [ConsoleContentAssistPDETest](https://github.com/rherrmann/gonsole/blob/master/com.codeaffine.console.core.pdetest/src/com/codeaffine/console/core/acceptance/ConsoleContentAssistPDETest.java). It uses a [ConsoleBot](https://github.com/rherrmann/gonsole/blob/master/com.codeaffine.console.core.pdetest/src/com/codeaffine/console/core/pdetest/bot/ConsoleBot.java) that encapusulates the key stroke simulation and a [custom AssertJ assertion](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html) that hides the details of waiting for the shell to open and finding the table, etc. ([ConsoleAssert](https://github.com/rherrmann/gonsole/blob/master/com.codeaffine.console.core.pdetest/src/com/codeaffine/console/core/pdetest/bot/ConsoleAssert.java))

With such a test in place we were able to [implement a walking skeleton](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Walking+skeleton). We developed individual parts of the content proposal code test-driven with unit tests.

Instead of writing your own *bot* you may also look into [SWTBot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) which provides an API to write UI/functional tests.

Comment: Indeed, SWTBot was a better choice than writing my own bot. I expected the test to be more complicated, but it was not